# Use php to show custom pages to each individual

Tags: php, joomla, file-get-contents, joomla3.0

I am creating a website on Joomla and want to have a private page for each individual user. If anyone knows of the best way to do this apart from giving each individual their own group, this is the way I would like to try:

I want to create a page where php will match a file name based on the user id of the logged in user. This is the code I have so far:

```
<?php

$user = JFactory::getUser();
$user_id = $user->id;

$profilepage = file_get_contents ("user" + $user_id +"file.txt");
echo $profilepage;

?>
```

This gives me the user id in a variable, and I would like for the correct profilepage to show. For example, if User594 is logged in, then I want the file to be used for $profilepage to be "user" + 594 + "file.txt"...for an actual file name of user594file.txt. Is this possible? Or is there a correct way of doing this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `$profilepage = file_get_contents ("user" . $user_id ."file.txt");` this isn't JS, use periods.

Comment: This worked by using periods....thank you!

Comment: No problemo, enjoy. You can delete the question. It's been answered.

Comment: If you don't want to delete the question, then your question will remain in the unanswered category. Either that, or I will post an answer and you can accept it. The choice is yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you *probably* chose not to delete your question and not hearing from you in comment in regards to a comment to you, I decided to post my comment as an answer.

You're presently wanting to use `+` signs. This isn't the character to use in order to concatenate.

In PHP, you need to use dots/periods:

```
$profilepage = file_get_contents ("user" . $user_id ."file.txt");
```